# How to open a windows Protocol Handler URI from Python

Tags: python, skype

How can a Python script invoke a supported URI like `im:sip:<colleague@company.com>` on windows (this example opens a chat/Skype window)?

I know the following works from a command prompt, complete with ugly `""` hacks to allow the `<>` angle brackets.

```
start "" "im:sip:<colleague@company.com>"
cmd /c start "" "im:sip:<colleague@company.com>"
```

but `subprocess.run(shlex.split(cmd))` won't support either of these. The first claims that `start.exe` cannot be found and the second just won't accept the same input (I've tried quite a few variations because of quote-handling but I can't reproduce the result).

There's probably a better way than invoking `cmd` anyway...

Answer (score 0):

I'll post my own answer but I'm hoping there's a more platform agnostic solution out there.

Using `explorer.exe` seems to do the trick

```py
  subprocess.run(shlex.split("explorer im:sip:<colleague@company.com>"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
os.startfile("im:sip:<colleague@company.com>")
```